# Social network with a blogg/news feed. blogg entry displayed 4 per row. (3 too meny)

Tags: php, mysqli, social-networking

social network" mostly for fun, and now im displaying 8 enrtys at per row, i think it's something with the foreach function, i don't fully understand it, can someone explain what values im supposed to put in. Right now i have this code.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statusA)){
foreach($row as $rows) {
  echo '<div class="statusholder">
            <div class="status-img">
                <img src="' . $row['Bild'] . '"/>
            </div>
            <h4 class="status-who">'. $row['user'] .'</h4>
            <p class="status">' .$row['status']. '</p>
        </div>';
}
```

}

This is my SQL question

```
$statusQ = "select * from status";
$statusA = mysqli_query($mysqli,$statusQ);
```

So right now i have 32 blogg enrtys on the "news feed wall" but im supposed to have 4.....
Also It's not displayed in UTF-8 :/ how can u do that, i've tried to using

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

on both the index.php page and the "action" pages where i upload statuses to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off; to get just 4 results you should limit the results when querying the database.
The query can look like this: `select * from status limit 4`

If you only want the four latest you should order the results by using this kind of query: `select * from status order by tillagdTid desc limit 4`

If you have trouble displaying your results and  å, ä, ö displays as something else you should have a look at PHPs utf8_decode() and utf8_encode(). They are simple to use and will most certainly solve your problem with encoding.
http://php.net/utf8_encode
http://php.net/utf8_decode

Comment: Thanks Alex but this didn't solve my peoblem, now i stil get 4 rows from the database as i did before, but it still displays 8 differant version of the status, it kinda copys itself.

Comment: @MånsDahlström if you could remove the "inner" `foreach($row as $rows) you should not be getting the duplicates. Cause you are actually not using the new $rows anywhere.

Comment: @MånsDahlström If that didn't help I can probably help you further in a chat. :)

Comment: I acctully need help getting the blogg post in UTF-8 right now even before it is in the database it's not UTF-8, maybe I should start a new thread about this? @alex

Comment: @MånsDahlström I believe it is encouraged to start a new separate question for that problem. :)